# JPA Entities generation using JAX-WS on Netbeans with customized Methods

Tags: web-services, jpa, netbeans, eclipselink, jax-ws

What I need is to have some specific methods (toString()) on my entities in order to be able to use them on my WebService Client (so I don't have to re-write them every time I Refresh my Webservice from Glassfish).

I ask this because I noticed that the only methods that are generated on my Client are the getters and setters of my fields, even if I write toString() on the Server side of the Webservice.

I guess the question is there a way to force customized methods to be deployed to the Application Server, so that those entities can reply to a toString(), for instance, on the Client?

```
package entities;


import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
public  class Auxiliarfiles implements Serializable {
  @Column(unique=false,updatable=true,insertable=true,nullable=false,length=38,scale=0,precision=0)
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;


  @Column(unique=false,updatable=true,insertable=true,nullable=true,length=255,scale=0,precision=0)
  @Basic
  private String description;
  @Column(unique=false,updatable=true,insertable=true,nullable=true,length=255,scale=0,precision=0)
  @Basic
  private String name;

  public Auxiliarfiles(){}


 public Long getId() {
     return this.id;
 }
 public void setId (Long id) {
    this.id = id;
 }
 public String getDescription() {
     return this.description;
 }
 public void setDescription (String description) {
     this.description = description;
 }
 public String getName() {
    return this.name;
 }
  public void setName (String name) {
    this.name = name;
   }
  public String toString() {
     return this.getId() + " - " + this.getName();
   }
 }
```

Thanks in advance!